# Javascript- How to Set a Cookie based on url Parameter

Tags: javascript

URL:
http://example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3?reco_id=xxxx

xxxx is the actual value (transaction number).

1. set a cookie "xxxx"
2. move oder page > call "reco_id"

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem: Do you have trouble getting the value from the url? Do you have trouble setting the cookie value? Do you have trouble navigating to the desired target url?

Answer (score 1):

You could access the query part of the url via `document.location.search` and the cookie string via `document.cookie` and modify the latter. To achieve this a cookie library like https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie might be helpful.

But JavaScript has no built in helpers to read individual query parameters from the complete query string. Check out this question: [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to extract the cookie parameter from the URL. Unfortunately, browser JS provides no built in method to parse URLs. I prefer using [jQuery.parseParams](https://gist.github.com/kares/956897).

Then you can use `document.cookie` to store the cookie value. Setting cookie in this way can be cumbersome, so you can use a library such as [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Then you can do something like this:

```
var params = $.parseParams(document.location.search);
$.cookie('reco_id',params['reco_id']);
```

Additional resources:

1. [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)
2. If you are not using jQuery, there are some good vanilla JS methods outlined here :

   - [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)
   - https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie